# Search array returning multiple values

Tags: php

I'm searching a database that returns multiple entries but I'm not sure how to then query the returned data?

The search can return up to 20 results (although this is unlikely) an example of the returned array is as follows:

```
RESPONSE: relationships/search Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [relationship_id] => 1487400
            [legal_form] => Sole Trader
            [display_name] => Jones Jones t/a 
            [relationship_status] => Prospect: Hot
            [telephone_number] => 02075387446
            [telephone_number_2] => 
            [mobile_number] => 
            [email_address] => smith@smith.com
            [date_of_birth] => 
            [registration_number] => 
            [vat_registration_number] => 
            [postcode] => 
            [creation_date] => 2017-09-14
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [relationship_id] => 1487399
            [legal_form] => Sole Trader
            [display_name] => Smith Smith t/a 
            [relationship_status] => Prospect: Hot
            [telephone_number] => 02087653458
            [telephone_number_2] => 
            [mobile_number] => 
            [email_address] => smith@smith.com
            [date_of_birth] => 
            [registration_number] => 
            [vat_registration_number] => 
            [postcode] => 
            [creation_date] => 2017-09-14
        )

)
```

Could anyone offer any advice?

**EDIT**

I feel I'm being a bit silly as I cant work out what I need to do to access the `objects` within each key?

Heres my code:

```
$relationship = postRequest('relationships/search', array('mobile_number' => $phone, 'email_address'=>$email, 'return_multiple_flag'=>Y));

     if(isset($relationship->relationship_id))
         foreach ($relationship as $object) {
             if($object->object_property == $phone && $email && $email != 'none@none.com'){
                return $relationship->relationship_id;
             }elseif($object->object_property == $phone){
                return $relationship->relationship_id;
             }elseif($object->object_property == $email && $email != 'none@none.com'){
                return $relationship->relationship_id; };
    };
```

I know the `foreach` is wrong.

Comment: Advice - read [ask] and [mcve]. Currently it is unclear what you try to achieve.

Comment: Apologies for my question being unclear. I will endeavour to update the question to make it less obscure.

Comment: Depends what you mean by "query". If you just want to output them, or examine something specific within each row, then loop through them with a for(each). Any basic PHP/SQL tutorial online will show you some sample code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an array of `stdClass` objects.

You can access them through the numerical key, starting with 0:

```
$obj = $array[0]; // First element in the array
```

Or, you can loop through them:

```
foreach ($array as $obj) {
    // code here
}
```

You can access properties of the object using the `->` operator:

```
$id = $obj->relationship_id;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That helps hugely. Thanks.

Comment: I feel like I'm being a bit silly here but I'm not sure how to access the objects within each key?

Comment: `if (count($relationship) > 0) { ` You are checking the array has at least one row.

Comment: `if($object->telephone_number == $phone && $object->email_address == $email && $email != 'none@none.com'){`

Comment: Hope these help you!

Comment: great to hear, all the best1